# Specify content when rendering with helpers

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

When I want to give a context to the rendering helpers, how can I do this?

I only manage to do this with the `{{render}}` helper.

```
{{render 'product-type-leaf' type}}
```

Is this also possible with `{{partial}}` and `{{view}}`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `with`:

```
{{#with someObject}}
  {{partial 'some-partial'}}
{{/with}}
```

However, you really shouldn't do this. Whatever you're using `render` for should probably be a component. Then you'd just pass the `type` into it, and work with the local variable in your component's template.

Comment: Is this in the spirit of replacing views with components towards Ember 2.0? 

I read your gist about this, but using components for everything needs a mindshift. Do you know some good resources about the use of components for almost all views?

Comment: Currently your best bet is to spend 5 hours or so with React. It really just takes a shift in thinking from components as completely reusable widgets (e.g. `<date-picker>`) to domain-specific UI elements (e.g. `<product-type>`). Once you start doing that it really cleans things up. One building block for your whole app.

Comment: Install the React inspector chrome extension, fire up instagram.com, and look through their component markup to get a sense of how you'd break down a website into components.